# CNN - Backpropagation of a Convolutional Layer

Tags: c++, c++11, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I am building a CNN with just convolutional layers (so far).

I used the same algorithm as for ANNs. Because the Conv layer isn't fully connected and has shared weights I'm not sure how to calculate gradients and appropriate statistics for this. I tried to average the &Delta weights and use the average to backprop. After a few tests I don't think that this works and it makes the iteration computations very slow (1 iteration per second instead of 80).

How do I properly backprop Conv layers?

And it would also be nice if anyone had any information or a link regarding backprop of other layers (like Pooling).

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for these type of questions. Try : http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A convolution can be interpreted as a fully-connected layer whose matrix of parameters is very sparse and where several values are shared. The backprop is simply the transpose of that matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There is many algorithms of SGD (Stochastic Gradient Descent) you can choose to backpropagation. You can try to see some of them like 
- Momentum
- AdaGrad
- AdaDelta
- Adam ...